# how to access the following html code from console?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to use browser console to change the text color and font size of the four rows below the row Other: Under the presets section of the website https://indiebubbler.github.io/metro/ . i know that set attributes can change the css but i am having trouble accessing those four rows in the console to apply the setAttribute to it.

[Edit : I understand that stackoverflow recommends including code snippet rather than link to the website but in this particular case the task is related to the DOM and thus it is better option to directly open the website and code in developers console.]

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I understand that stackoverflow recommends including code snippet rather than link to the website but in this particular case the task is related to the DOM and thus it is better option to directly open the website and code in developers console

Comment: It's not a matter of recommending, it is mandatory for the question to be on-topic. The goal of Stack Overflow is to publicly share answers to problems/questions with others that have the same problem. If the URL you are pointing to ever changes content or becomes unavailable, this question becomes completely useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open dev tools
- Select the element you want to change using the cursor icon
- Inside the element console right click on the specific element, go to copy and copy js path:
  [image]
- Go to the console paste the copied path and change the styling using .style.property = "...":
  [image]
- Note: once the page reload everything is reset to default style if you want this to stay use stylus or tempermonkey or any extension that inject CSS/JS code into the website